# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component when using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using Redux to manage a global `Dialog` component. I pass the `children` components to the `Dialog` component using Redux actions.

A functional example is in this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-keldysh-uuolb?file=/src/App.js

There is no problem opening the `Dialog` and rendering its `children`, the problem is when I try to pass a state with one of its children:

```
const handleOpenDialog = () => {
    dispatch(
      openDialog({
        title: <DialogTitle />,
        content: (
          <DialogContent
            form={form}
            setForm={setForm}
            setSubject={setSubject}
            subject={subject}
          />
        ),
        actions: <DialogActions form={form} />
      })
    );
  };
```

The `Dialog` renders fine, but I can't update the state of the props I passed to the `Dialog`. The component that calls the function to open the `Dialog` is this one:

```
export default function ContactSupport() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [form, setForm] = useState("");
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState("");

  const handleOpenDialog = () => {
    dispatch(
      openDialog({
        title: <DialogTitle />,
        content: (
          <DialogContent
            form={form}
            setForm={setForm}
            setSubject={setSubject}
            subject={subject}
          />
        ),
        actions: <DialogActions form={form} />
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <Paper onClick={handleOpenDialog}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} container justify="center">
          <Typography>Icon</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Typography align="center">Contact support</Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

My intention is that when I click on this component, the `Dialog` is rendered with the `state` which is in this component. I need the `state` in this component, because I need to access it in the `DialogActions` component as well, because this component will call the `API` with the action.

In Firefox an error is shown in the console:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

I'm not sure why this component is unmounted, if it still shows in the `Dialog` background.

Any help to solve this issue, even with another design pattern for this, is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone with same case as mine, I solved it using a `state` action to set the component `state` in redux.

This way I have access thru the whole application, then I don't need to pass the state by props. The downside is that I'll have to remount the component every keystroke.

I updated the codesandbox with the solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround I use when I don't want to search for the cause of re-rendering is defining a `this._mounted=false` in `constructor`, setting it to `true` in `componentDidMount()` and back to `false` in `componentWillUnmount()`.

Now you use `setState` like so:

```
if (this._mounted) this.setState({...});
```

It's a version for a class component, but I hope you'd know how to use it in FC.